# Can't resolve project reference because of indirect dependency on current target framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ssis, package

Can someone please translate this into English?

```
The primary reference
"Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly
"mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
which has a higher version "2.0.3600.0"
than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

Is this a problem with the target version of MY PROJECT or a problem between .Net and the SQL Server library I'm trying to use?

I need to target .Net 2.0, but I don't care what sub-level (2.0.3600).  Can this be changed?  I looked under project properties and didn't see anyway to change the sub-level (only between .Net 2, 3.5, 4, etc.)

What do I need to do to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem (for SQL Server 2005) by building my project against .Net version 4 instead of 2.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, rather than mine then, since it's definitely easier and more reliable than what I had. :-) I like the points, but I think it's more important for the next person to have the same problem to be able to see the answer that actually worked.

Comment: That's honorable and self-less.

Comment: You said that you need to target .NET 2.0... What about those projects that need to stay on 2.0?

Answer (score 5):

I found this issue on [another forum](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551532/cannot-build-project-in-2010-when-project-has-reference-to-ssis-2008-dlls-sqltask-manageddts-etc) and at least it's explained.

> Thanks for taking the time to send us
>   this issue.
>
> It appears that the reference is to
>   mscorlib 2.0.3600, which is the Beta 2
>   of .NET 2.0. Normally this would just
>   work itself out, with the version
>   number of the shipping product being
>   hight, but, in this case, the Beta 2
>   number is actually higher. Ooopppss...
>
> In order to determine exactly where
>   this reference is coming from, we
>   really need to start with a detailed
>   log. You can get this by executing the
>   following from a Visual Studio command
>   line: msbuild {projectname} /v:d
>   /t:rebuild /fl
>
> This will create an msbuild.log file.
>   Please attach this to the bug so that
>   we can take a look.
>
> As is indicated in the thread, you can
>   use an app.config to redirect.
>   However, this will only work with and
>   executable, and it only band-aid's the
>   real issue, which is that you are
>   using an our of date DLL.
>
> You could also use
>   SpecificVersion=true on the reference.
>   However, this defeats multi-targeting,
>   and is an unsupported advanced
>   scenario. This is basically because
>   once you do this, you may get other
>   errors, and you really have to know
>   what you are doing to get this to
>   work.
>
> We need to determine the actual
>   assembly that is referencing .NET v2.0
>   Beta 2 so that we can determine how
>   you can get the latest version of the
>   non-Beta2 assembly.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Chuck England Visual Studio Platform
>   Program Manager - MSBuild

There are also two possible options for fixing it posted.  One is to update the version of the Microsoft.SQLServer.msxml6_interop.dll in the GAC with a version that has the correct manifest.  I'm not sure where you'd get the dll but it's worth reading through the posts on the other site.

The other option is a .config file modification.

Here's what they put for a .config change, but the poster said it worked in an executable, but not in a class library.  I hope it helps.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v1.0.3705">
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="mscorlib" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.3600.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```